# How to find expectation of joint uniform distribution?[solved]

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose that $a$ and $b$ are the true lengths of the sides of a rectangle. We measure them and measurement error is induced such that the results are
$z_1=a+x$, $z_2=b+y$, where $x$ and $y$ are independent, continuous and uniformly distributed random variables on the interval [-1,1]. The task is to calculate the area $z=z_1z_2.$ Determine $E(z)$ and $Var(z)$.

1) The expected value of $z$

$E(z)$

$=E(z_1z_2)$

$=E((a+x)(b+y))$

$=E(ab+ay+xb+xy)$

$=E(ab)+E(ay)+E(xb)+E(xy)$ | expectation is linear operator

$=ab+aE(y)+bE(x)+E(x)E(y)$ | $x$ and $y$ are independent

$=ab+a\dot{}0+b\dot{}0+0$ |$E(x)=E(y)=0$

$=ab$

2) The variance of $z$

$Var(z)$

$=E((z-E(z))^2)$

$=E((ab+ay+xb+xy-ab)^2)$

$=E((ay+xb+xy)^2)$

$=E((ay)^2+abxy+ayxy+xbay+(xb)^2+xbxy+xay^2+xyxb+(xy)^2)$

$=a^2E(y^2)+abE(x)E(y)+aE(x)E(y^2)+abE(x)E(y)+b^2E(x^2)+bE(y)E(x^2)+aE(x)E(y^2)+bE(x^2)E(y)+E(x^2y^2))$

$=a^2E(y^2)+b^2E(x^2)+E(x^2y^2)$

$=a^2E(y^2)+b^2E(x^2)+E(x^2)E(y^2)$

$=...?$

Is this correct?

Comment: Hint/Solution: It is way easier if you just use the properties of expectation and variance.

Comment: The joint PDF is not what you write -- and, as already mentioned in a comment, one does not need it anyway.

Comment: I have edited the original post, please take a look at it.

Comment: To conclude, note that $$E(x^2)=E(y^2)=\int_{-1}^1t^2\frac{dt}2=\ldots$$

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have enough reputation to comment I have to do it in reply. First part looks good, but for second part I will give a hint. What you can say about $\sigma_x^2$ and $\sigma_y^2$ when variance is defined as $\sigma_x^2=E(x^2)-E(x)^2$ given that $x$ and $y$ are uniformly distributed?

Comment: I already figured it out, but thanks anyway :)